# How can I display only Cases without Case Managers using Drupal Views

Tags: civicase, drupal-views, relationships

I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.9, if it makes a difference.

I want to use Drupal Views to display only CiviCase cases that *do not* have case managers.

I feel as though I'm close... so close, but I'm not quite there yet. This is what I have set up.

I have a view that displays cases in a table format. I've add a *subject* field and a *contact* field to the view. I then added *CiviCRM Case Contact: Case Contact's ID* as a relationship, and to that I've added *CiviCRM Contacts: CiviCRM Relationship (starting from contact A)* which is set to use only the case manager relationship type, but is not required.

For filters, I've added *(CiviCRM Relationship (starting from contact A)) CiviCRM Relationships: Case ID (empty)*.

This **almost** works as I want it to. However, if a single client has multiple cases, and any one of those cases is assigned a case manager, none of their other cases will show up. I think this happens because the relationship is fetched via the clients ID number and not via the case ID, though as far as I can see, there are no views relationships that will allow me to  fetch a case relationship via the case ID.

I can supply more information if needed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are close.
Add a Contact A relationship and use  CiviCRM Relationship (starting from contact A).

Add both Display Names fields.

In filters, add CiviCRM Relationships: Contact ID B and set it to empty.

Here is a copy of a view of CiviCRM Cases.
[image: Empty Case Role View]

And a pic of the filter:
[image: Empty Case Role Filter]

**Update to solve multiple cases:**

To solve the folks with multiple case types issue, I created this page view but filtered for only one case type.  I then added attachments to the view page for all other case types.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working for me. It is still excluding any case with a client who has multiple cases where any one of them has a manager.

Comment: You can read some of the issues about multiple cases here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/if-contact-has-multiple-cases-how-do-i-filter-a-view-to-show-only-case-roles-as

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I may be barking up the wrong tree, here. Seems like manipulating views to do what I want it to do here might be about as much work as just writing a custom block to do what I want it to do... Will have to bang my head against it some more. Thanks again!

Comment: No, it's pretty easy.  The only downside is I had to create an attachment for each case type.

Comment: Updated answer above for multiple case types.

Comment: I'm just going to approach this in a different way. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: No problem. Please share whatever you come up with.