# How can I show only Cases that have no Case Manager?

Tags: civicase

I asked a similar question recently, but I wanted an answer specifically for Drupal Views. I'm broadening my scope now.

I thought I had an answer to my question via Case Reports. I can show only those cases without managers by implementing the "Case Role(s)" filter and setting it to "Is not one of" "Case Manager". This gives me the results I expect. However, I can't actually navigate to individual cases from the report. Instead when I click on the case subject, a modal window pops up that shows very little information about the case.

I would like to have a list of cases without managers with links to manage the case.

I'd prefer a built-in civi solution, but I'm fair with PHP and not averse to some custom coding if need be.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up the page view as mentioned in your other post [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/how-can-i-display-only-cases-without-case-managers-using-drupal-views), you can add a global text field with a rewrite to `civicrm/contact/view/case?id=[id]&cid=[id_1]&action=view`.

If you need to set it up for folks that may have **multiple case types** then filter this page by a single case type.

After you have this view behaving as desired, add an attachment and on the attachment, change the case type filter to your next case type.

Add an attachment for each additional case type.